# Setup the dependency using ivy and fetch with Maven

Tags: grails

I would like to know what is Maven repository and ivy dependency for grails, how to setup the dependency using ivy and fetch the maven, could anyone answer this

Comment: This section of documentation might be helpful [Dependency Resolution](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#ivy).

Answer (score 0):

> Maven repository--
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_repositories.htm
>
> Ivy dependency--
>   http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html
>
> Ivy in grails -- Take a look at document that @Alidad suggested--
>   http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#ivy

And here is an example of how you can do this in grails:

In your BuildConfig.groovy 
//find link to maven repo that has a jar

```
repositories {
...
...
mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
}
```

//goto that repo and find the group:name:version for the jar. then

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.ibm:com.ibm.mq.pcf:7.0.1.7'
}
```